# How to add a link to an anchor in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, hyperlink, anchor

I'm creating a website with Drupal 7.

I've a contact block at the bottom of the page (as a footer page), but I need to put a link into a menú with an anchor. I mean, when an user press that link, it must scroll down the page to the contact block.

How could I do this? I don't see anything.

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module **[Menu attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes)** is your life saver, install it, so you can add the ***name*** attribute to your link

Comment: Adding a name attribute to a link does not make it an anchor link. you need to add #anchor to the link somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use the [Menu token](http://drupal.org/project/menu_token) module in order to get the path to the current page for the anchor link. Path for the menu item should be something like:

```
[current-page:url:path]#footer
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple! You just create a link and go to page content edit option through Drupal admin. In the bottom of edit content page you will get a URL path settings, there is url alias field on there. You just put path in your field.

[image]